# Labeling places using local fonts like Singhala and Tamil fonts in ArcMap or QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, labeling, font, internationalization

I downloaded the Keyman desktop for the local keyboard/fonts. I would like to encode location names using Tamil/Singhala fonts in the attribute table and then use it to label the map. However, after saving the attribute table with the local fonts, it converts to question marks. Below are the images for before and after saving the table.

If the downloaded fonts are unrecognizable by ArcGIS/QGIS, how do we know which ones can be recognized?

[image: beforeSaving]

[image: afterSaving]

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If the font is installed on the system, it should be accessible to ArcGIS at least. Assuming it's a valid font type. Have you tried using the desired font with anything? Can you add more detail to your question, or a graphic example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: This *might* help: http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/36806 I'm not very familiar with font issues like this. What might be happening is you type/paste characters into the field and they temporarily display correctly, but when you open the table again it tries to display the characters using the default table font and you get ?s instead. Is the font you are trying to use Unicode? Find a version that is? You might try creating labels from that field and setting them to the font. Sometimes things won't display right in the table but will in the map.

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS, if the dataset is saved in the right encoding and the labels are set to your desired font, the labels should be displayed correctly. I'm not so certain about the effect on the attribute table if the characters are not available in the font the attribut table uses.

If you continue to have issues, please share a small sample of your data for test purposes. Please add information about the correct encoding.